Grouping Spark Dataset under a condition: error margin
I'm trying to get familiar with Spark by playing with a Dataset. The dataset has the following columns:
[ "zipcode", "city", "loc", "pop", "state"}

It contains information about cities in USA (location, population...). Here is a example of a row:
{ "zipcode" : "10009", "city" : "NEW YORK", "loc" : [ -73.979591, 40.726188 ], "pop" : 57426, "state" : "NY" }

What I want to do is sum up the population of different regions of the US. To get me a step closer to this I was thinking of trying to sum up the population of all the cities that were a certain distance away from each other. So if the difference between the location of two cities is less than 5Km, then group them in the same row and add their populations up. How could I do this?
Also, I assume that in order to do this I have to cast the "loc" column to a tuple of ints (or something similar) and I don't know hot to do this:
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

object SimpleApp {

  def analyzeUSPopulation(implicit spark: SparkSession, path: String): Unit = {
    val file = "us_population.json"
    val data = spark.read
    .json(path+file)
    .withColumn("pop", col("pop").cast("int"))
    //.withColumn("loc", TURN INTO A TUPLE OF INTS)
    .cache()

    val result = SOMEHOW_GROUP_BY_REGION.show()
  }
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
    implicit val path = "..."
    analyzeUSPopulation
    spark.stop()
  }
}

Thank you!
I've tried looking at groupBy and at agg but since I'me new to Spark I don't know how I could achieve my purpose.

I was asked a similar question in an interview once, was not able to figure it out back then but I researched about it. Its quite simple if you are able to relate to the Math behind it. The formula is Haversine Distance Formula
If you follow the below steps, you can easily do this
1.) convert the loc column from an array to a tuple of double values
2.) use haversine formula on obtained lat and long
3.) simple-join to group nearby cities
4.) filter clause for cities in 5km range
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, DoubleType, IntegerType
from math import radians, cos, sin, sqrt, atan2

df = df.withColumn("latitude", F.col("loc")[1].cast(DoubleType())).withColumn("longitude", F.col("loc")[0].cast(DoubleType()))


def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    R = 6371.0 
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    return R * c

haversine_udf = F.udf(haversine, DoubleType())

joined_df = df.alias("df1").crossJoin(df.alias("df2")).filter(F.col("df1.zipcode") != F.col("df2.zipcode"))

distance_df = joined_df.withColumn(
    "distance_km",
    haversine_udf(
        F.col("df1.latitude"), F.col("df1.longitude"),
        F.col("df2.latitude"), F.col("df2.longitude")
    )
)

close_cities_df = distance_df.filter(F.col("distance_km") < 5)

result_df = close_cities_df.groupBy("df1.city").agg(
    F.sum("df1.pop").alias("total_population")
)

result_df.show()

